# wordpress change charset and serialize all data with new charset

Tags: php, wordpress, character-encoding

Is there A way to `deserialize` the wordpress data (sidebars, widgets , theme options) after changing charset  in  `wp-config.php`.
In my website, I accidentally (I didn't know that) changed the `DB_CHARSET`  in `wp-config.php`, and it is crashed my website , I lost all my sidebars information, theme options, styles etc.
And even when I set the Charset back, it doesn't repair.
Is there a way to get the old options and how?

Comment: Hi, you changed `DB_CHARSET` to what ??

Comment: to nothing just a blank ''. define('DB_CHARSET', '');

Comment: Read this https://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets